# Ubuntu 19.10 change keyboard language freeze

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, freeze, gnome-tweaks

I have fresh installed Ubuntu 19.10. When I'm changing keyboard layout all system freezes a bit. I recorded [video](https://youtu.be/zIb2p1n80pA), that shows what is happening in `journalctl` while I'm changing language. Also I've shown `htop` with process consuming a lot of CPU when I'm changing layout fast (at the end of the video I'm rapidly tapping hotkeys to change layout, and music video is freezing constantly).

Here is that process `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3`

Here is what journalctl says each time I change layout:

```
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
лют 20 13:37:25 gurland-pc gnome-shell[17519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
```

---

### System information

**OS**: `Ubuntu 19.10`

**Kernel**: `5.3.0-40-generic`

**Mutter**: `mutter 3.34.1`

**Gnome-shell**: `GNOME Shell 3.34.1`